# Is entry of context menu in Chrome dev tool correspond to UI view, and if so, how to show it on the page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In 'console' tab of Chrome browser there is a context menu dropdown. Please refer to below.

[image]

When i am inspecting an element on the page, the context menu dropdown will show the 'context' that the element is in. My question is: does this context correspond to a sub 'view' in the webpage? And if so, how can i display the view that's related to the context?

e.g. the entire web view is always corresponding to 'top'. if i select a context under 'top', how can i 
know what sub view/area it corresponds to?

Comment: The context corresponds to the main page document or to a frame (`<frame>` or `<iframe>` elements), and the "isolated worlds" of chrome extensions content scripts in each document/frame.

Comment: @wOxxOm this specific page i understand. i am looking for a generic solution, e.g. if the page is a frame->iframe->iframe structure, i.e. a frame inside a frame, i want to know how i can see where the frame is in UI based on context menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such feature so you can request it on https://crbug.com.

Meanwhile here's a workaround:

1. Switch to `Elements` panel
2. Select the context in the context dropdown in the console toolbar
3. Open **devtools-on-devtools** and run this console command in its window:

   ```
   (async () => {
     const dom = UI.panels.console._view._consoleContextSelector._dropDown._selectedItem
                   .target().model(SDK.DOMModel);
     if (!dom._document) await dom.requestDocument();
     UI.panels.elements.revealAndSelectNode(dom._document);
   })();
   ```
4. Save this command in [devtools snippets](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets) to quickly re-run it later.

#### How to open devtools-on-devtools:

1. Open devtools first and switch its `Dock side` in the menu to a detached (floating) window

   [image]
2. in the now detached devtools press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> on MacOS,
   which will open **devtools-on-devtools** in a new window